# bitmapdata record video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, red5, flashdevelop

is there any sample on using array bitmapdata to record video from webcam and generate flash movieclip file? i want to record sound as well without using red5/flash streaming server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video part *may* be possible at very low framerates, but you would have to port an FLV encoder into AS3, which is no trivial task. It would also be very memory intensive.

As for audio, there is simply no programatic access to raw microphone data from within the Flash player. If you want to record audio you must you a server like FMS or Red5.

Answer (score 2):

For the video part, there is [SimpleFlvWriter](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/?p=14) (for AIR).

For the sound part, Flash do not allow you to directly record a microphone input, BUT, there are some alternatives talked in [getMicrophone()](http://www.getmicrophone.com/).

Comment: totally agree with you but this is suitable for local saving and not for internet traffic. For example a 1280x780x24fpsx15sec would result in some 100MB file which after compression with ffmpeg for example will result in an approx 1.5Mb file which makes this solution absolutely not confortable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any library out there can generate swf files form Flash in runtimeWhat you can do is to pass all the bitmapdata to backend, PHP for example. Then use PHP to generate a swf file with MING library or something similar.

For security reason, you cannot record sound from microphone.